# How to resolve two perl version in MacOS?

Tags: perl

I installed perl with brew then I found that when I type `perl -v` it says `5.18.1` but when I type in `which perl` it says `/usr/local/bin/perl` and if I type `/usr/local/bin/perl -v` it says `5.28.1` which I believe is the brew version. The problem now is that I can run some perl script in terminal without problem (5.18.1) but run in python by calling subprocess, it will call 5.28.1 version which causes the script to fail. Any idea how I can use 5.18.1 inside the subprocess?

Comment: Did you create an alias for `perl`? Try `type perl`.

Comment: It says `perl is hashed (/usr/bin/perl)`

Comment: Aha, got it. So I should use this version instead of the local version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446580/why-does-type-which-say-that-which-is-hashed) and [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105876/what-does-rm-is-hashed-mean) for an explanation of hashed commands. Perhaps you edited your `PATH` after your shell had already made a hash entry for the `perl` command.

You can delete the hash entry with

```
hash -d perl
```

And then `perl` should resolve to the same location returned by `which perl`.

To remove all hashed commands, say, after you update the `PATH` variable, the command is

```
hash -r
```